# Cannot connect to CUPS

Tags: networking, printing, cups-lpd

CUPS is not working.My printer isn't listed in the printers' program.

All it says is, "Printing service is not available. Start the service on this computer or connect to another server."

Things I've tried:
sudo apt-get purge cups && sudo apt-get install cups --install-suggests

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this evening I had the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge cups && sudo apt-get install cups
```

This worked for me on an ASUS netbook running Lubuntu 16.04 x86. I subsequently conneted successfully to my Canon ip7200 via Wifi.